# Rails Strong Parameters either in root or nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I want to be able to support a set of parameters in either the root params object:

```
?foo=a
params.permit(:foo)
```

Or in a nested object:

```
?bar[foo]=a
params.require(:bar).permit(:foo)
```

I'm passing parameters into that controller from a form object, so the nested object happens naturally, but I'd like to also be able to pass the params in the root object in the query string and support both.

Is there an elegant, non-hacky way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is like `[]` with an exception when the value is missing (much like `Hash#fetch`). You can instead just use `[]` directly to get the nested structure if it's there, and fall back to the root `params` otherwise:

```
(params[:bar] || params).permit(:foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

remember that require is different as permit.

The `require` method ensures that a specific parameter is present. is not necessary to use on nested ones, it makes sure that the required one come in the params or it will throw an error.

you can work with nested attributes like this

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  person: {
    name: "Francesco",
    age:  22,
    pets: [{
      name: "Purplish",
      category: "dogs"
    }]
  }
})

permitted = params.permit(person: [ :name, { pets: :name } ])
permitted.permitted?                    # => true
permitted[:person][:name]               # => "Francesco"
permitted[:person][:age]                # => nil
permitted[:person][:pets][0][:name]     # => "Purplish"
permitted[:person][:pets][0][:category] # => nil
```

you can check the documentation on this [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)